# Why does BluetoothManager.OpenGattServer() always return null on my Nexus 7?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm trying to get this tutorial working for my Nexus 7 (2012) running cyanogenMod (so it has BT LE) using BluetoothGattServer Android APis- http://www.jayconsystems.com/tutorial/android_ble_nrf8002/

However, setting up the GattServer is not working and always returns null.

After this:

```
gattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(
                    getApplicationContext(), mBluetoothGattServerCallback);
```

gattServer is always null.  Any ideas on why that could be?

Comment: Look at this link. I hope will useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181843/android-using-bluetoothgattserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it is because the Nexus 7 (2012 edition) doesn't support Bluetooth LE, as it has a Bluetooth 3.0 radio inside.

The 2013 Nexus 7, however, does support Bluetooth LE.